# Should we and how do we do unit/integration test locking in hql queries?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, integration-testing, grails-orm, spock

We have several sql/hql/criterias that we thought it's best to put unit/integration tests on. Meaning testing the actual logic and potential result of the query.

Problem is, some of them have pessimistic locking in them.

Question is how do people unit/integration test them?
Maybe someone can give some kind of pattern on how this is done?

(If at all relevant, we are using spock as our testing framework.)

Comment: I suggest integration-testing with a real database or in-memory database, since you want verify the sql logic.

Comment: But how to assert pessimistic locking?

Comment: To assert that your query is using pessimistic locking, just ensure that you're using setLockModeOn(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_XXX) on query creation. This can be done using just unit test. It's not your responsibility to test implementations of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: yes, but what if the query is sql/hql, not using criterias?

Comment: Just my curiosity, how do you do pessimistic locking in HQL and SQL with gorm?

Comment: with sql, just with "for update", for hql, it's like what you mentioned.

Comment: I would do unit testing to check if the string 'for update' is present in SQL. For HQL and criteria I would check if the code is calling the lock method. This ensure that your code is doing pessimistic lock. To do some integration test you'll have to work manually with two transactions to check the pessimistic lock. Resuming, unit tests to code where you want pessimistic locking (checking for string 'for update' and etc) and one integration test to verify that the pessimistic lock works as you expect.

Comment: Is the two transaction approach normally done? I was going for that approach, but that totally overrides the rollback process of the test data of a test, causing the data to spill to other integration tests without manual cleaning. So tests becomes a lot longer.

Comment: We do some integration test that uses two transaction or two threads for some concurrency tests. But our integration test always use the same DB state, meaning that our DB is awalys recreated for each test class. For integration test with @Stepwise annotation, the integration test commits to DB for each test (happy path testing and concurrency testing). Otherwise the test uses the rollback policy for each test (independent tests).